# Kubernetes ingress routing- Asterisk (*) is not working in ingress Path rules

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

We have various Asp.net core containers with REST APIs hosted in Azure Kubernetes Service. Each REST API service implements many HTTP methods with different routes but has common base route (based on controller name).

Requirements is to route the request to different service based starting route value, e.g. All requests starting with “/user” route user service or products APIs requests to product service.
We have added path as "/user/* ", "/product/* " in the path section of the kubernetes ingress.
Asterisk (*) is not working

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/) you need to use regex.

```
path: /foo/.*
```

Comment: Meaning any character after "/foo/" repeated zero or more number of times

Comment: well, this is the exact match of what he is asking for, so I felt there is no point in clarifying this